# Optimal camera settings for standing clothing model in indoors environment

Tags: lens, depth-of-field, camera-settings, models, photo-shoot

I am trying to shoot a clothing photoshoot where a model will always stand in the same spot in an indoors studio with 2 lightboxes and a white backdrop.

What would be the best camera settings with a lens 18-105mm so I get the best possible texture (maximize Depth of Field) and avoid any move if the shutter gets a bit slower?

Comment: Are your lights strobes or always on lights?

Comment: Always on lights. 2 softboxes of 350W each

Comment: In my opinion the light is low. That is not the best scenario. You will need to shoot in large aperture for that. If it is a commercial project rent some flashes or buy some economic flashes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use flash. The two main advantages of flash will both help with what you are trying to do.

- Strobes place a lot of light on the subject at the time of exposure. Typically at a much lower cost than the same amount and quality of light from continuous sources.
- The short duration of light put out by many strobes allow you to freeze any motion of your model even when using shutter speeds not fast enough to do it with continuous lights. Just keep the ambient lighting low enough so as to not affect the exposure.

The main disadvantage is that you can't see the light you are getting with most strobes before you take the shot. Some strobes do have a modeling light feature that allows you to do this, but they tend to be more expensive than basic strobes. A lot of photographers overcome this by shooting tethered to a laptop or computer when in the studio so they can get instant feedback on a larger screen than the camera's rear LCD.

With enough light available you can set the aperture at whatever you need to get the depth of field you desire without worrying about shutter speed and motion blur.